# Delete older files first in chunks (i.e. lets say 1000 at one time) from directory that contains millions of files using Java 7

Tags: java, file, java-7

as in my current scenario which is ok for less number of files, we are using Comparator for sorting files in reverse order of modification

```
//performance overhead for listing million of files at same time
File[] files = directory.listFiles(); 

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){

 public int compare(File f1, File f2)
{
     return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
}  

}
);
```

after sorting we can delete it

```
//performance overhead for iterating million of files at same time
for (File file : files ) { 
 final long lastModifiedTime = new Date().getTime() - file.lastModified();
       //delete files older than 3 days(i.e 72 hours)
        if (lastModifiedTime > 72*60 * 60 * 1000) {
               file.delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest any good solution for that problem....

Comment: If they are sorted, why bother to go any further in the list after finding the first that isn't older than 3 days?

Comment: facing performance issue due to large number of files...looking for some solution to get older files in chunks and than delete those old files..as in our current system there is one thread that checks for older files into directory in every 2 mins for deletion

Comment: I see... You are looking for a new solution. I was merely stating that this small change would turn into a performance boost in your existing solution.

Comment: @at888 Use package nio to retrieve huge list of files using `Files.newDirectoryStream()` then use `Arrays.parallelSort(Path[],Comparator<Path>)` to sort them quickly using parallel tasks. To delete your old files, create a File with the specified last modified time then use `Arrays.binarySearch(Path[],Path,Comparator<Path>)` to find the first index which verify your condition then iterate over this index to delete all others files.

Comment: @Naruto Biju Mode Thanks, will try this solution